# CFL condition in polar coordinates.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation, stability-theory

Is there a Courant–Friedrichs–Lewy (CFL) type condition when dealing with the wave equation numerically in **polar coordinates**? For Example [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/112900/discretizing-the-wave-equation-in-polar-coordinates) it is mentioned for the wave equation but there isn't a explanation as to where it comes from. Any references on this subject would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Cartesian grids, the stability condition can be derived by inserting complex exponential solutions $\exp(i (k_x x + k_y y + k_z z + \omega t))$. From this you obtain a discrete dispersion relation $f(k_x,k_y,k_z,\omega)=0$ and the stability condition is the condition under which this equation cannot have complex $\omega$ solution (or at least no solutions with $\Im(\omega)<0$).

The reason this works at all is the happy coincidence that $\exp(i (k_x x + k_y y + k_z z + \omega t))$ is also an eigenfunction of the *discrete* derivative operators on a cartesian grid - it is an exact solution of the discretized equations.

In other coordinate systems, exact discrete solutions are not known, and deriving exact stability conditions is much more complicated.

That being said, there are ways of doing it. [This thesis](https://osuwmcdigital.osu.edu/sitetool/sites/electrosciencepublic/documents/publications/dissertation/Chilton_Ryan.pdf) derives an exact stability condition for discretized Maxwell's equations in terms of (I oversimplify a little) eigenvalues of the discrete curl operator (eq 2.113), making no assumption on the coordinate system.

There is also [this paper](https://biblio.ugent.be/publication/5753970/file/5846187) (eq. 31), but the derivation is not exact: they assume eigensolutions of the form $\exp(i (k_r r + k_{\phi} \phi + k_z z + \omega t))$ which is only valid in the far-from-the-origin limit.

I am speaking from memory here, but I'm sure Taflove's book "Computational Electrodynamics: The Finite-Difference Time-Domain Method" (not sure which edition) has a discussion of the stability of a discretized wave equation in cylindrical coordinates. They do not calculate it exactly, but they give numerical results that indicate the stability condition depends on how close to the origin you get.

One more thing: the formula in your link
$$c^2\frac{dt}{\min(dr^2,d\phi^2)}\leq\frac12$$
cannot possibly be correct since $dr$ and $d\phi$ have different units.

Comment: Very Helpful. Thanks