# The real CFL condition for cylindrical laplacian

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation, finite-differences, stability-theory

I've been exploring the CFL (Courant-Friedrichs-Lewy) condition in polar coordinates and have observed that previous inquiries haven't yielded a satisfactory answer. I've come across [this paper](https://www.math.arizona.edu/%7Eleonk/papers/polarFD7.pdf) which appears to provide a more compelling explanation for the CFL condition in polar coordinates. However, I'm uncertain about the implementation, especially with regard to the M term. I'm not sure how to obtain it—do I need to utilize the wave solution and compute the derivatives?

[cfl condition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfUUS.png)

I'd appreciate any insights or guidance on this matter. Thank you!

These are the other questions about CFL condition that I found in stack exchange [CFL CONDITION IN POLAR COORDINATES](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1874881/cfl-condition-in-polar-coordinates) and [CFL condition in polar coordinates](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/26313/cfl-condition-in-polar-coordinates)